# Why am I getting "Error: bad instruction" in an enum in C?

Tags: c, enums, compiler-errors, arm, cross-compiling

This is weird and doesn't have any sense to me. I added the following enum in a .h file u-boot:

```
typedef enum LP5521_Patterns_Tag
{
  LP5521_EB_ALL_GOOD,
  LP5521_EB_CLEAR_ALL,
  LP5521_EB_CONNECTED_TO_INTERNET,
  LP5521_EB_ENERGY_BRIDGE_FOUND,
  LP5521_EB_NO_SIGNAL,
  LP5521_EB_PLUGGED_IN,
  LP5521_EB_POOR_CONNECTION,
  LP5521_EB_SERACH_WIFI,
  LP5521_SET_COLOR,
  LP5521_SET_CURRENT,
  LP5521_SET_COLOR_CURRENT,
  LP5521_PATTERNS_TOTAL
}LP5521_Patterns_T;
```

But then when I try to compile it I get the following errors:

```
include/configs/lp5521.h: Assembler messages:
include/configs/lp5521.h:7: Error: bad instruction `typedef enum LP5521_Patterns_Tag'
include/configs/lp5521.h:8: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `{'
include/configs/lp5521.h:9: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_eb_all_good,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:10: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_eb_clear_all,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:11: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_eb_connected_to_internet,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:12: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_eb_energy_bridge_found,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:13: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_eb_no_signal,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:14: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_eb_plugged_in,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:15: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_eb_poor_connection,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:16: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_eb_serach_wifi,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:17: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_set_color,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:18: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_set_current,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:19: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_set_color_current,'
include/configs/lp5521.h:20: Error: bad instruction `lp5521_patterns_total'
include/configs/lp5521.h:21: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `}'
```

I notice that at the top it says **Assembler messages** but I don't understand either. There is a .c file that I already added that contain a bunch of typedef enums and I'm not getting any errors in those.

Could anyone please help me to figure out what is going on here?

I don't know if this helps but I'm adding some code to u-boot and cross-compiling for imx6.

Thank you!!

Comment: The messages don't look like from a C compiler, but more from an Assembler.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You haven't posted the source code that includes your header file.

Comment: Probably, the problem is *before* the code fragment you posted, not in it.

Comment: You can't just include a C file into an assembler source and expect it to work. Notice that the error messages have converted your "enum values" to lower case. Assembler mnemonics are not case sensitive. The assembler is trying to *assemble* your C code.

Comment: I din't know why would the assembler be complaining. I haven't added any include in any assembly file. As I mentioned I'm using the u-boot source code and I have just added a .c and .h file and tried to recompile. I'm just wondering in what kind of situations this could present since I have never seen some error like this before.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap this enum like this :

```
  #if !defined(__ASSEMBLER__) 

  typedef enum LP5521_Patterns_Tag
  {
  LP5521_EB_ALL_GOOD,
  LP5521_EB_CLEAR_ALL,
  LP5521_EB_CONNECTED_TO_INTERNET,
  LP5521_EB_ENERGY_BRIDGE_FOUND,
  LP5521_EB_NO_SIGNAL,
  LP5521_EB_PLUGGED_IN,
  LP5521_EB_POOR_CONNECTION,
  LP5521_EB_SERACH_WIFI,
  LP5521_SET_COLOR,
  LP5521_SET_CURRENT,
  LP5521_SET_COLOR_CURRENT,
  LP5521_PATTERNS_TOTAL
  }LP5521_Patterns_T;

  #endif
```

defining _ *ASSEMBLER* _ symbol for Assembler and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

U-boot contains a lot of CPP pre-processed assembly files (i.e. `.S` rather than `.s`); the board config header is probably the one thing that's included in just about *everything* (C files, assembly files, linker scripts) as it generally defines not just options but board-specific physical addresses, etc.

Ergo putting anything other than #defined symbols in there is pretty much asking for trouble.